# SoapUI TestCase - How to extract raw response string for the second step

Tags: rest, soap, soapui, testcase

I use SoapUI to make a simple test:

1. Call a REST service (POST) which returns me something like
   "key:value"
2. Call a web service (SOAP) with one of the element = the value from step 1

I just search the SmartBear Forum and the SoapUI documentation but did not find how to extract the response, like it would be similar to ${myFirstStep#Response/rootelement/element} if it was XML. But the REST response is not XML (then I guess xpath function does not apply in my case).

I would prefer a solution without scripting if possible. Is there a SOAPUI documentation about these variable parsing? I did not find it on [SoapUI site](http://www.soapui.org)

EDIT: a Groovy script solution would be perfect if someone have a idea how to make it. I checked the Groovy documentation on the soapui site but I do not find what I want.

Comment: As far as I know you will need to use a groovy script.  If you decide to go that route I can help out.

Comment: @chrismead, i was not intereasted until now, but a solution with Groovy seems the one which will resolve that kind of issue.

Answer (score 1):

If your rest response is in JSON Format you can change it in XML format..and if you dont want to change it in xml format you can use property transfer step in pro version there you will see a option to choose ReponseAsXml in property box of source.Then you can write your normal Xpath to transfer that property.Its very simple.

Or even by right clicking on your node in Pro version you can directly transfer that node any where in your testcase.But its pro feature.Best way to do it in soapui free version change your response in Xml format.

Comment: I am with the Soap-UI Standard (free) not the Pro version. In the free version there is as well a responseAsXML but it does not work as the return is not xml nor json but just a text in format key:value.